# How to select rows only with Active status

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this oracle table:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
        USERID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        GROUPID INTEGER,
        SPECIALNUMBER VARCHAR2(60 ),
        USERNAME VARCHAR2(50 ),
        PASSWD VARCHAR2(50 ),
        DATETOCHANGEPASSWD DATE,
        ADDRESS VARCHAR2(60 ),
        STATEREGION VARCHAR2(50 ),
        COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50 ),
        USERSTATUS VARCHAR2(30 ),
        TELEPHONE VARCHAR2(50 ),
        DATEUSERADDED DATE,
        USEREXPIREDATE DATE,
        DATEUSERLOCKED CHAR(20 ),
        CITY VARCHAR2(50 ),
        EMAIL VARCHAR2(50 ),
        DESCRIPTION CLOB
        )
```

I use this SQL query to fetch rows:

```
SqlStatementSmall = "SELECT c.*"
            + " FROM (SELECT b.*, rownum rn"
            + " FROM (SELECT a.*"
            + " FROM USERS a"
            + " ORDER BY %s %s) b"
            + " WHERE rownum <= ?) c"
            + " WHERE rn > ?";
```

How I can modify the SQL query to select rows only with status "Active"?

Best wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SqlStatementSmall = "SELECT c.*"
            + " FROM (SELECT b.*, rownum rn"
            + " FROM (SELECT a.*"
            + " FROM USERS a"
            + " ORDER BY %s %s) b"
            + " WHERE rownum <= ?) c"
            + " WHERE rn > ? AND USERSTATUS = 'ACTIVE'";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have one question - in this way the word `active` is case sensitive. How I can make it not case sensitive?

Comment: AND UPPER(USERSTATUS) = 'ACTIVE'

Comment: @user1285928 - I don't really understand what you mean with the word `active` being case sensitive. Either your database is case sensitive or not. If the values on your table can be both `ACTIVE` and `active` then I don't recommend you to use `UPPER` because if there is an index on `USERSTATUS`, then your query won't use it. You can use `" WHERE rn > ? AND USERSTATUS IN ('ACTIVE','active')"` for example

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on where you want the filter applied.  I am guessing you want it before you start your rownum limiting (I imagine you are doing pagination).  In that case you want:

```
SqlStatementSmall = "SELECT c.*"
            + " FROM (SELECT b.*, rownum rn"
            + " FROM (SELECT a.*"
            + " FROM USERS a"
            + " WHERE UPPER(USERSTATUS) = 'ACTIVE'"
            + " ORDER BY %s %s) b"
            + " WHERE rownum <= ?) c"
            + " WHERE rn > ?";
```

I put the UPPER() function in there, because you asked about ignoring case.